# Stop audio when call is received in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on turn by turn navigation app and adding voice to it so the user can hear the current step they are navigating to. I have a scenario i.e. when the audio for current step is on and in the middle if I receive a phone call, currently my app doesn't stop the audio for navigation. I would like to stop the audio whenever there is an interruption i.e. particularly for phone calls.

I have lot of code, but I think it's the way I create set category is affecting it hence adding piece of code. I am on iOS 16.

I tried using .soloAmbient as the category instead of playback and with that I wasn't hearing any voice even when there was no active phone call. How do I stop the turn by turn navigation audio during an active phone call?

***Code:***

```
let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()

func speakNavigation() {
    let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: formatted)
        if let voice = self.chooseVoice() {
        log.debug("Using voice \(voice.name) (lang=\(voice.language), quality=\(voice.quality.rawValue)) for speaking directions.")
        utterance.voice = voice
    }

    synth.speak(utterance)

    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error: Could not set audio category: \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error: Could not setActive to true: \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }  
}

private func chooseVoice() -> AVSpeechSynthesisVoice? {
    let allVoices = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices()
    let preferredLanguage = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.currentLanguageCode()

    let voicesMatchingLanguageAndLocale = allVoices.filter { $0.language == preferredLanguage }
    
    let premiumQualityVoices = voicesMatchingLanguageAndLocale.filter { $0.quality == .premium }
    if !premiumQualityVoices.isEmpty {
        return premiumQualityVoices.first
    }

    let enhancedQualityVoices = voicesMatchingLanguageAndLocale.filter { $0.quality == .enhanced }
    if !enhancedQualityVoices.isEmpty {
        return enhancedQualityVoices.first
    }

    if preferredLanguage.equalsIgnoringCase("en-US") {
        let allEnglishVoices = allVoices.filter { $0.language.hasPrefix("en-") }

        let enhancedQualityEnglishVoices = allEnglishVoices.filter { $0.quality == .enhanced }
        if !enhancedQualityEnglishVoices.isEmpty {
            return enhancedQualityEnglishVoices.first
        }

        if !allEnglishVoices.isEmpty {
            return allEnglishVoices.first
        }
    }

    if !voicesMatchingLanguageAndLocale.isEmpty {
        return voicesMatchingLanguageAndLocale.first
    }
    
    return nil
}
```